# Learning New Testament Greek through Bible verses

Tags: new-testament, greek, biblical-languages

I have been searching the internet for hours but the only resource I could discover so far that teaches biblical Greek a bit like I imagine is [Little Greek 101:
Learning New Testament Greek](http://www.ibiblio.org/koine/greek/lessons/)

It's not comprehensive but maybe it can give you a bit of an idea of what I am looking for, that is, why not take individual verses and explain the grammatical concepts with those verses, building up the vocabulary at the same time?

So far there is nothing that does exactly this, but maybe you can help me out and point me to some book or resource?

Comment: I throughly recommend William Mounce's _Basics of Biblical Greek_ and then, afterwards, Daniel B Wallace's _Beyond the Basics_. But there is no shortcut, easy and entertaining way. Just hard graft. If one is lacking in language skills, then Young's _Analytical Concordance_ is ideal as he helps us, massively, by not assuming any Greek knowledge at all. Of course, this is for the _Textus Receptus_ / Authorised Version only. I cannot help outside of that.

Comment: https://dailydoseofgreek.com/ seems like what you're after. But it's really meant to suppliment an actual course in NT Greek.

Comment: @curiousdannii this is indeed almost exactly what I envisioned, if you add it as an answer I can mark it as the solution

Comment: I found that Wikipedia contains a lot information for specific passages with detailed information also about Greek readings, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acts_8
This information is quite helpful to study NT Greek.

Answer (score 2):

Here are my two cents:

Step 1. Learn the alphabet if you haven't already

Step 2. Get an interlinear (be it online or otherwise)

Step 3. Get a grammar (I know...that's probably not what you want to hear but that's ultimately what you will do after steps one and two)

Now, for what it's worth I think your approach is very much like mine was early on and it's a great start.  You can get by with just steps one and two.  In fact, I had a nice interlinear laying around for years before I finally learned the alphabet.  Once I finally learned it, I then learned how to read and commit to memory some simple verses like John 1:1 and 1 John 4:8.  Steps one and two can be combined if your interlinear has a section on learning the alphabet.  Some even have a primer on grammar and then you can have steps 1-3 in one resource.  But...you'll always want more than a primer in grammar.

For grammars you have recommendations for Mounce and Wallace in another answer.  Those are fine and I've read through them plenty but I'll recommend another often overlooked one: The Elements of New Testament Greek.

There are three editions of this work spanning something like 100 years.  The first was authored by H.P.V. Nunn, the second by John Wenham, and the third by Jeremy Duff.

I've got editions one and three in PDF format (they are easy to find and the first is public domain) and the second edition with the key in print.  I love Wenham's style of teaching - it was just something that I immediately identified with.

The first edition is available at [Key to the elements of New Testament Greek](https://archive.org/details/keytoelementsofn00nunnrich)

UPDATE: I didn't mean to link to the answer key above but I'll leave it because it's nice to check your answers.  The actual book is available at [The elements of New Testament Greek](https://archive.org/details/elementsofnewtes00nunn)

As far as interlinears go, I'll go out on a limb and recommend another unpopular one: [The Kingdom Interlinear Translation of the Greek Scriptures](https://www.jw.org/en/library/bible/kingdom-interlinear-greek-translation/books/), published by Jehovah's Witnesses.  It's completely free and available online.  The Greek text it contains is the Westcott and Hort of 1881.  Some might object to it because they object to certain renderings of the NWT (I do not).  However, in the online version, you get just the Greek with the word-for-word English translation (sans NWT on the side).

Sure, if you Google it you will find plenty of negative reviews...but they aren't all negative and, really, if it's online, free, and helps you learn Greek...what's the big deal?

The article [How Knowing Greek Led Me to Know God](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/101987204) contains some positive non-JW reviews at the end.

Here's another short one which I'll quote:

> “Miracle” Greek Text
>
> When reviewing “The Kingdom Interlinear Translation of the Greek Scriptures” for “The Classical Journal,” Thomas N. Winter of the University of Nebraska observed:
>
> “An original Greek text for two dollars is something of a miracle, and it should not surprise us that it took a world-wide group of Bible students to pull it off. This is no ordinary interlinear: the integrity of the text is preserved, and the English which appears below it is simply the basic meaning of the Greek word. . . . A translation in smooth English appears in a slim column at the right-hand margin of the pages. . . . I think it is a legitimate and highly useful aid toward the mastery of koine (and classical) Greek. After examining a copy, I equipped several interested second-year Greek students with it as an auxiliary text. . . . After learning the proper pronunciations, a motivated student could probably learn koine Greek from this source alone.
>
> “The text is based on that of Brooke F. Westcott and Fenton J. A. Hort (1881, repr.), but the translation by the anonymous committee is thoroughly up-to-date and consistently accurate. Where both the King James and the Revised Standard, for instance, have ‘wise men’ for the Greek magoi (e.g., Matt. 2:1, 2:7, 2:16), the Kingdom Interlinear has ‘astrologers,’ a more correct and informative rendition. The book has been very carefully compiled and printed.
>
> “In sum, when a Witness comes to the door, the classicist, Greek student, or Bible student alike would do well to bring him in and place an order.”​—April-May, 1974, pp. 375-376.

Source: [“Miracle” Greek Text](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/101980529)

Thankfully, now it's online and not two dollars!

Anyways, you won't regret even learning just a little Greek (even just the alphabet).  It's not a requirement for a Christian, of course, but so rewarding and dare I say, "fun"!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your tips and approach. As interlinear I prefer the received text. I like the book "The Englishman's Greek New Testament" which is also available online here: https://archive.org/details/englishmansgreek00 It features the KJV text in the margin. As for the grammar I started reading "Teach Yourself New Testament Greek" by D.F. Hudson which is really nice and interesting to read, but it does not follow the approach I mentioned in my question (available also in the links of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Foster_Hudson))

Comment: Thanks for those recommendations.  Your link to the Englishman's Greek NT seems broken but I found it by searching on archive dot org.  I've got it starred to read later - it looks very good!  As far as grammars go, I really don't know of one that exists that starts by breaking down an entire scripture.  Of course, that doesn't mean that it doesn't exist because I haven't read them all!  But, I do really think that a motivated person can learn Greek with your proposed method by just using an interlinear (as reflected in the quotes of my answer above).

Comment: Yeah sure, thanks. I think I've got some good tips here now and I should be doing fine going forward. The fixed link for the "The Englishman's Greek New Testament" would be: https://archive.org/details/englishmansgreek00step

Answer (score 1):

I was taught Greek years ago in college. So, I'm not very familiar with some of the "learn by video" modules that are available.  However, there is a companion site to the *aleph with Beth* site called [Alpha with Angela.](https://freegreek.online/about/). That might be a decent place to start.

In my own experience, though, the conversational approach begins to hit limitations when reading through the NT Greek.

Comment: "*the conversational approach*" isn't really what is needed. Most people will want to be able to read it, not speak or write it. I took German 111 at university, and it didn't require learning any vocabulary or even pronunciation; it was strictly how to parse a sentence and look up the words in a lexicon. Its purpose was to help researchers read scientific papers.Vocabulary etc. naturally grows over time, without one's having to memorize it. For most of us, that's also all that's needed for NT Greek (and OT Hebrew).

Comment: @RayButterworth  As the old saying goes, *"dē gustibus non dusputandum est."* I don't get into debates over individual tastes/preferences.  I too have found limited use out of conversational models. But there are others I have met who have found them useful. I am sharing a resource in this post, not pontificating.

Comment: Hey thanks this is a very nice resource, although not exactly what I asked for but really helpful 

Answer (score 0):

I have tried that website, ibiblio, and it was useless and annoying to me on the most basic level; most of such apps or tools are gimmick to be honest, and not even free. I advise against it. Duolingo, on the other hand, has been perfect in starting any language. There is no need to create or find any Duolingo alternative for koine greek. [John Dobson's](http://bakerpublishinggroup.com/books/learn-new-testament-greek-3rd-edition/110/students/esources/themes/60) *Learn NT Greek* is the one you are looking for, it is without a doubt the best book any new learner can get. After you practice practised for basics on duolingo, and after this book, I recommend Rodney Decker's and Merkle & Plummer's intermediate book, and Stanley Porter's Fundamentals of NT Greek.